# XMLHttpRequest not works when Asnyc is set to true

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In my webpage :http://ravi4pk.in/chat

You can see in my first XMLHttpRequest I've set Asnyc parameter to 0 i.e., false.

When i set it to true, it not works, what is wrong?

Comment: Please post your code here in your question (you can [edit] it), instead of [just linking your page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use async you need to use onreadystatechange event like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = txt;
    }
};
```

Comment: Will this really work? Also, Can you please explain what was wrong?

Comment: @RaviPK Only in synchronous ajax call you will be able to get the text after the send method, if you do asynchronous call you need a callback that will be executed after content from the server arived and you do this with onreadystatechange.

Comment: That's it! Very nice sir! That was my problem. Can you please take a time to understand me how to do the `callback`?

Comment: @RaviPK the callback is in my answer, it will be called when state will change and it get the text when http request is finish.

Comment: So nice teacher! I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Oh my goooood,god! So nice, It worked Sir! This world needs more developers like you.